# centosで外付けディスクのUSBを抜き差しした際に自動でmount/umountしたい

Tags: linux, centos

定期的に外部ドライブへのバックアップを実施するために、
デバイスを接続した際に自動でmount、デバイスを外した際に自動でumountを実施したいです。

自動でmountを実施する方法はautofsで実施できそうなのですが、
自動でumountを実施する方法が分かりません。

物理的にデバイスを外すと自動でumountされるものでしょうか。

どなたかご教示頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autofs利用時のunmountされる条件は、デバイスを外したらではなく「一定時間マウントした領域にアクセスがない場合」です。
安全にデバイスを取り外すには、dfコマンドなどでマウントが解除されていることを確認してからの方がよいでしょう。

バックアップ目的であるならバックアップの処理をバッチファイルにまとめて、最後にunmountも済ませてしまうのも一つの方法かなと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「一定時間マウントした領域にアクセスがない場合」にunmountされるんですね。